# Is "emptiest" a logically correct term?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree, gradability

There are some adjectives that are logical binaries, e.g. *empty* — either the noun is empty or it isn't.

Can we apply a superlative degree to such adjectives? E.g.

> This is the emptiest these roads will ever be / have ever been.

Comment: Logically, yes -- in the proper context, of course. Grammatically,  however, no. _Empty_, as a disyllabic adjective ending in /i/, takes the morphological _-est_ superlative suffix instead of _most_. It should be _the emptiest_; a definite article is normal.

Comment: But in terms of logic, i'm curious...how can a binary value hold a superlative degree.
In this case, either the road is empty, or it isn't (prescribing to correct use of "empty").

Comment: Who says it has to be binary? _Of the sixteen silos surveyed, no. 11 was the emptiest, no. 3 the fullest._

Comment: In fact, in real language, as opposed to abstract argumentation, remarkably few adjectives are restricted to being logical binaries. People complain about "most unique", but it's a common expression (particularly in advertising, it must be added).

Comment: [Terra Antarctica: Looking Into the **Emptiest** Continent (2007)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OyNPPgAACAAJ&dq=emptiest&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SjyVUfTvHabu0gWs7YDgDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA), by [William L. Fox](http://www.wlfox.net/). Who's apparently *published poems, articles, reviews, and essays in more than seventy magazines, has had fifteen collections of poetry published in three countries, and has written eleven nonfiction books about the relationships among art, cognition, and landscape*, so I guess we can accept him as a competent writer.

Comment: You can warp your mind into all kinds of contortions over binary interpretations of adjectives. Take "wet" for example. One could argue that a thing is either wet or it isn't. Yet there are varying degrees of wetness just as there are of blueness, universality, or emptiness.

Comment: **empty** *adjective* (*emptier, emptiest*) http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/empty "On the evacuation of being, we might turn to Hegel, believed by some to offer, in his Science of Logic, the high noon of speculative metaphysics: here being may be the first thought, **but it is the emptiest**, because the least determinate." William Desmond, *The Intimate Strangeness of Being* -- GR.

Comment: *emptier* & *emptiest* are indeed "words". However, they are either used in a literary sense or in an appropriate context. (Which is why they appear so rarely.) OP's example sentence needs a better word than *empty*.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase. Your very premise that language has to be logical is wrong. It doesn't have to, it never was, and probably never will be. Questions about logic can be taken to Philosophy or another sister site. As far as the language is concerned, "this is the emptiest these roads will ever be", "this statement is a lie", and "colorless green ideas sleep furiously" are all perfectly grammatical and idiomatic, with "this is the emptiest these roads will ever be" offering the additional benefits of being universally used and universally understood.

Answer (score 6):

"Empty" by itself can be viewed as a binary option (either it's empty or it isn't), but how close an object is to being empty is clearly a matter of degree suitable for comparative and superlative usages.  A sixteen-ounce bottle with only one ounce of liquid in it is "nearly empty", and is also clearly "emptier" (i.e. having more empty space inside it) than the same sixteen-ounce bottle with twelve ounces of liquid in it.

Comment: It is no more clearly 'emptier' than Nero is 'deader' than Napoleon. Only the fact that 'emptier' is reasonably commonly used to mean 'more nearly empty' licenses this usage (amongst those more descriptivist).

Comment: Taking your example into account, would it be right in saying that "emptiest" is a (for lack of a better word) poetic word?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Except that nobody uses the word "deader" to mean "died less recently than". People do use it to mean "more closer to the state of being dead than". Google books search finds "deader than a doornail", "He's been more dead than this", etc.

Comment: @MrS: I'm saying that Hellion is begging the question: he's assuming that the descriptor 'emptier' **can** be used because it would seem to make some sort of sense. I and then you, not he, mention the fact that usage is an at least equally important factor. You interpret my nonce 'is deader than' logically to stand for 'died less recently than' but rightly say that **transparency doesn't license it**. That is the point I made. And we can't generalise - a number isn't 'more positive' if it is 'nearer to being positive' than another.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 The more normal expression in British English is "dead *as* a doornail", not "deader *than* ..." which is, of course, impossible. Dead is dead; empty is empty. You can't really have degrees of "deadness" nor degrees of emptiness. You can be *nearly empty* or *nearly dead*, but both have the implication that you are moving towards a final state of actually being dead (or empty). You suggest that you can use *deader* to mean *closer to the state of being dead* - I don't think you'll find that in British English - *closer to death* would be the normal expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I at first misunderstood what you were saying in the same way that Mr Shiny did, but now I get it, and I completely agree. It's not *clear* what "emptier" should mean any more than it is clear what "deader" should mean. Both are completely valid words and have valid uses (I am "among the more descriptivist" here), but there is no way to generalize and determine what these meanings are. Only by looking at real usage can we determine the meanings.

Comment: Though in the case of both "emptier" and "deader" that meaning seems to generalize to "being closer to the state of X than", but I doubt that can be extended to all cases, and in any case "closer to the state of" is itself open for interpretation and its meaning not immediately clear.

Answer (score 3):

We often speak of things being empty or full by degrees, with the classic example being the glass half-full or half-empty. While [the comparative and superlative for *full* are much more common than for *empty*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=empty,emptier,emptiest,fuller,fullest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), the latter still appear in all major dictionaries that I checked, [including American Heritage, Collins, and Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emptiest).

Furthermore, there's established usage in classic literature. From [Melville](http://books.google.com/books?id=yDvuEjhAw-gC&pg=PA1067&dq=%22emptiest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i2aVUeDuOefziQLx44CoDw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22emptiest%22&f=false):

> “What! would you have my epitaph read thus: – ‘Here lies the **emptiest** of mortals, who was full of himself?’ At best, your words are exceedingly ambiguous, Mohi.”

Comment: Yes - the Ngram shows the idiosyncratic difference in usage between the comparatives ... of _full_ and _empty_. That is, there appears little logic in the decision to use _fuller_ far more frequently than _emptier_ / _more empty_ when both usages 'bend the rules' to a similar degree. I'm fairly sure that the modification of (semantically) absolute adjectives is usually restricted to a pragmatic (emphasising) role as in _quite dead_ (= **dead!**), _absolutely impossible_. Gradation here seems quite rare (and I would mark 'most unique' wrong). I'll try to think of a few other examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  You say "most unique" is wrong, and I'm pretty sure I agree with you.  Unique is one word I seldom use.  Uniqueness is part and parcel of being, whether you are a person, place or thing.  From "no two snowflakes are exactly alike," to "no two persons are exactly alike," to "no two places are exactly alike."  Who said, "You do, and do not, step into the same river twice"?  A preacher once said, "God does not make duplicates; only originals."  Each person is unique, each in his or her own way.  To say someone is unique is to state the obvious.

Comment: Even to say, "She has a singular intellect" is not only stating the obvious, but it is also kind of audacious in that the statement presumes one has examined every person in the world and concluded "she," of all humanity, is one-of-a-kind intellectually.  Of course, one can approach scientifically this question of intellect by conducting a study of a given number of subjects, complete with a protocol (a null hypothesis, a control group, accurate measurements, and so on) that reduces the possibility of inaccuracy and bias, but still, each subject's intellectual acumen is inexorably unique.

Comment: **Equal** - not the equivalent of 'identical' - has complex levels of meaning. '6 is more equal to 7 than 23' is nonsense, but 'I've never seen two more equal teams' (overall) makes sense - or at least sounds acceptable. 'This is more useless than that' sounds ridiculous, but 'There have been few more useless pieces of legislation' seems to work. '?/*This soup is more tasteless than that' but 'This article is even more tasteless than that' in the metaphorical sense works. '*She is more perfect' but 'A more perfect _Lady Macbeth_ I cannot imagine.' Highly complex.

Comment: I suspect that the imbalance between _fuller_ and _emptier_ is because it's a [marked opposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness), so people prefer using the unmarked word (_full_) unless they have a specific reason to call out emptiness. Also, I think a lot of things like _full & empty, black & white_ are absolute in some contexts but graded in others. For example: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/is-it-correct-to-use-the-comparative-adjective-blacker/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Marking is why “This is more useless than that” sounds weird; we'd say “That is more useful than this” unless we're really stressing uselessness, in which case you'd say “This is _even more_ useless than that.”

Comment: Useful is not an absolute adjective, whereas useless is. The opposite of useless is possibly essential.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's arguable; in general, _-ful_ and _-less_ are about as absolute as _full_ and _empty_ (i.e., not very). I think the negative forms are simply marked and thus not preferred for comparison.

Comment: I disagree. As does _Warsaw Will_ at http://random-idea-english.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/gradable-or-ungradable.html : _Adjectives with suffixes... most adjectives formed with the suffix: -less are ungradable. ... some adjectives formed with the suffix: -ful are gradable, some are not._ I'd offer _useful_ (/more / very useful), beautiful, careful, cheerful, colourful, doubtful, graceful, helpful, painful, powerful, restful, successful, thoughtful ... probably more than are ungradable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree with him right from “black and white are usually seen as absolute” – whiter teeth, blackest night. Wiktionary lists only _doubtless_ and _successless_ as uncomparable forms, and some examples like _careless, restless,_ and _thoughtless_ are widely used comparatively. Perhaps this is a good candidate for an ELU.SE question of its own?

Comment: Many adjectives formed with -less don't have counterparts ending in -ful, and most of these are probably ungradable. Childless, cordless, smokeless, eyeless, finless, gearless, heirless and lidless are just several that spring to mind. Wrt the absoluteness of _useful_ and _useless_, Google hits for "very useful" and "very useless" are in the ratio of 400 : 1.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed about _-less_ adjectives like _childless_ that aren't part of a gradable antonym pair. But for pairs like _useful/useless,_ I think that's just a sign that the pair is strongly marked, rather than half of the pair being absolute. Note that _totally useless_ isn't redundant. I'm trying to work up a question specifically about this issue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth New question posted here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114341/does-english-have-half-graded-antonyms

Answer (score 0):

There is also the semantic value that you have added in your sentence:"This is the emptiest these roads *will ever be/ever have been*." You are making a comparison and therefore need to use use the grammatical device of a qualification. You cannot say: "This is the empty these roads *will ever be/ever have been*." or "This is the emptier these roads *will ever be/ever have been*." You need to simply show that this particular state is unique and thus assign the superlative to the situation.--i.e., using empiest.

Comment: Wouldn't "This is as empty as the road will ever be / has ever been" be a logical alternative to it?

Comment: I would avoid using *empty* at all in this context. Personally, I would say something like "This is the *quietest* (as in *most quiet*) I've ever seen the road", or "This is the *least busy* the road has ever been".

Comment: @Rajan: that does not change anything it all, except proving to us that even you, subconsciously and contrary to own advice, consider *empty* not to be binary. *As empty* is still comparing things on a scale. You just chose a different construction to express the exact same idea: that sometimes it's emptier than other times, and sometimes the emptiest.

Answer (score -1):

Can you have an "empty" road? Would it not be more logical to say the road was **clear** or there was no traffic or no cars?

I checked and apparently you can. I didn't realize I was so old fashioned! [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=empty+road%2C+clear+road&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)
However, if you compare "emptiest road" with "clearest road" even on the American corpus the results are very different. [Ngram: emptiest vs clearest](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=emptiest+road%2Cclearest+road&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

And as for "emptier" being used to compare the quantity of liquid in two containers I would find it more natural to say: "A sixteen-ounce bottle with one ounce of liquid has **less** than a sixteen-ounce bottle with twelve ounces of liquid." **Little, less** and **least** and **few, fewer** and **fewest** ought to be used in preference to emptier and emptiest.