# Is there a difference between "less ambiguous" and "more unambiguous"?

Tags: meaning, differences, connotation, comparatives

Relevant examples:

> If you make the following changes your sentence will be less ambiguous.
>
> If you make the following changes your sentence will be more unambiguous.

Do these sentences have a significant difference in either meaning or connotation?

Comment: No one won't deny you nothing!  Can't disagree with that.

Comment: Possibly related: [Does English have half-graded antonyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114341/does-english-have-half-graded-antonyms)

Comment: I have to say, at first blush I thought this was an easy question and I was wondering why a 10k plus rep person asked it!  Then I tried to answer it, and read the answers of others.  This is a GREAT QUESTION!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Less ambiguous** is easier to understand because ambiguity can vary. By saying 'more unambiguous', the speaker or writer is saying that the sentence is not ambiguous but it could still use improvement. It could be that the speaker or writer is a polite person, and didn't want to suggest that your sentence had ambiguity.

**UPDATE:** Maybe the British English speakers are more polite! [LINK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20unambiguous:eng_us_2012,%20more%20unambiguous:eng_gb_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,more%20unambiguous:eng_us_2012;,c0;.t1;,more%20unambiguous:eng_gb_2012;,c0)

In actual usage 'more unambiguous' shows up 10% as often as 'less ambiguous' (warning: [N-gram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20unambiguous/%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29,%20less%20ambiguous/%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28more%20unambiguous%20/%20%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29%29;,c0;.t1;,%28less%20ambiguous%20/%20%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29%29;,c0#t1;,%28more%20unambiguous%20/%20%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29%29;,c1;.t1;,%28less%20ambiguous%20/%20%28more%20unambiguous%20%2b%20less%20ambiguous%29%29;,c1)), and it's pretty constant usage since 1950.

Despite the absolute nature of unambiguous, common usage doesn't strictly follow that definition. If one thing can be less ambiguous than another, then another thing can be more unambiguous than another.

[image]

In case you are curious, **more unambiguous** is most commonly followed by 'than' ([link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20unambiguous%20*&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t2;,more%20unambiguous%20*;,c0;,s0;;more%20unambiguous%20than;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20and;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20in;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20evidence;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20the;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20way;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20results;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20statement;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20information;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20terms;,c0)), and 'more unambiguous than' is most often followed by 'the' ([link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20unambiguous%20than%20*&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t2;,more%20unambiguous%20than%20*;,c0;,s0;;more%20unambiguous%20than%20the;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20than%20that;,c0;;more%20unambiguous%20than%20this;,c0)).

Answer (score 3):

Unambiguous is an absolute state. Hence, you can't be more unambiguous.

Whether or not you can be less ambiguous is difficult to say. Ambiguity may or may not be an absolute state.  For example, if the majority of a text is unambiguous but one point is ambiguous (such as my answer here!) does it make the whole text ambiguous?  Or, is it *slightly* ambiguous?  It seems more natural to be slightly ambiguous than say slightly unambiguous, though.

As the two expressions are commonly used, they are equivalent, though.

There are plenty of examples of this type of incorrect usage in English that have become completely acceptable.

Consider the words right and wrong. Technically you are either right or wrong.  They are both absolute states. Regardless of how many points you are wrong about, you are still wrong.

But, we all accept terms like more wrong and more right because they are intellectual expediences that allow for nuances to be explained more easily.

Great example from The Big Bang Theory:

> It's a little wrong to call a tomato a vegetable. It's very wrong to call it a suspension bridge.

**Update**  I've spent quite a few hours thinking this over, and I think I have a better answer:

When we describe absolute states yet use a modifier in front of them, we are actually just employing a linguistic shorthand.

When we say *less ambiguous* or *more unambiguous* we mean:

> Contains less ambiguous content than ...
>   Contains more unambiguous content than ...

In both cases it is the content that is being modified and *not* the ambiguity itself.

As neither of those rolls of the tongue (or pen, or keyboard), we say *less ambiguous*, etc.

Comment: If 'unambiguous' is absolute and non-gradable, I am puzzled as to how 'ambiguous' is gradable. If that be the case then logic dictates that 'unambiguous' cannot be the exact antonym of ambiguous, doesn't it?

Comment: This answer seems a little bit right.

Comment: @WS2 I agree with you, and I'm not sure how to resolve this ambiguity. Ambiguous seemed more gradable when I was writing this, but, I am swayed by your logic.

Comment: It is just a double negative.  I don't not misunderstand the issue.

Comment: Well, is it an actual double negative?  Not unambiguous would definitely be a double negative. But, less ambiguous seems more of a contradiction of terms, but perhaps not.

Comment: I count contradictions as double negatives.  We can call them whatever but to a person hearing this it performs a double negative.

Comment: @WS2 and Ryebread I believe that this is an example of the intellectual expediences I spoke of above.

Comment: WS2’s comment reminds me of a question I posted a while back: [Does English have half-graded antonyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114341/does-english-have-half-graded-antonyms) The question never really gelled, but you may find it interesting.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That appears to be a REALLY good question.  I will read it over later when I'm not at work!

Comment: You can't be *mostly right*? Or *mostly wrong*? Why not?

Comment: @WS2 I agree that *unambiguous* seems absolute. But you can have things that are a *little bit* anbiguous* or very ambiguous* or *possible ambiguoous*. *Dead* is dead, but *barely alive* works for me.

Comment: @bib I agree with the last bit, but in theory you're alive or dead (Schroedinger's cat aside). So, I believe this is the intellectual expediency I spoke of above.

Comment: Barely alive is almost dead. Is a little ambiguous almost unambiguous?

Comment: @MrHen that seems reasonable if you allow for the modification of an unmodifiable. Again, I think it's an attempt to let our brains express a nuance which is otherwise impossible to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is immense:
*Less ambiguous* is negative: your text was ambiguous, which is bad, and after the  the change it will be less bad.
*More unambiguous* is a compliment: your text already was unambiguous and the change will make it even better.

This is a general phenomenon which I, as a mathematician, find quite amusing: logically equivalent sentences are perceived as quite different emotionally according to the formulation used.

You don't believe me? Tell your friend the boxer that  he is more intelligent  than your neighbour and then that he is less stupid (which is logically equivalent) than his cousin and see (feel?) his different reactions...

**Remark**
It is true that *unambiguous* is essentially absolute (in which case the phrase *more unambiguous* doesn't make sense) but for the sake of argument one could claim that the answer *I don't think so* to the statement "2+2=5"  is unambiguous but that the answer *No!* is more unambiguous.

Comment: In your end example, neither is ambiguous and neither is more unambiguous than the other. *I don't think so* does not introduce ambiguity, it is a statement of your belief. That you might be wrong in your belief is not a matter of ambiguity.   I do agree with your mathematical assertion at the beginning, but you introduced the ambiguity at the end with your final statement.  Also, stupid and intelligent are not absolute states. Stupidity and intelligence are measurable. To put it into mathematical terms, there is a flaw in this proof but I don't think any of us have spotted it yet.

Comment: @David: ambiguity has nothing to do with my boxer example.I wanted to give an instance  of logically equivalent statements that are psychologically perceived as different. Stupid and intelligent are or are not absolute according to the context (you can say "John is less intelligent than Bill", but also ""Albert is stupid")   but this is irrelevant to my point that logic and psychology differ.