# Can ungradable adjectives be used as gradable?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

I was under the impression that **ungradable** adjectives cannot have comparative forms in any circumstances, because there are no degrees in those adjectives.

But I found a quotation from George Orwell containing an ungradable adjective ***"equal"*** and since then I wondered if there are other ungradable adjectives that can be used in comparative form.

> *"Some animals are **more equal** than others."* (George Orwell)

Comment: All English adjectives are gradable, but some are more gradable than others.

Comment: I think one has to say that it's usages, not the adjectives themselves, that are gradable. For instance, 'unique' is ungradable in its original sense, but  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unique) also gives a broadened sense 'Particularly remarkable, special, or unusual' which is gradable. 'Equal' as used by Orwell is a nonce broadening to illustrate the hypocrisy involved. 'His glass is fuller than mine' is idiomatic for 'His glass is more nearly full than mine'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of that passage is bitter irony: the  revolution was carried out under the principle "All animals are equal" but is subverted when Napoleon's party assumes dictatorship and rewrites the principle :

> All animals are equal, but some animals are more equal than others.

Logically and grammatically it's meaningless; but power trumps logic and grammar.

Comment: How very true..

Comment: And, to generalize, the (relatively rare) technique is used with other adjectives (though I can't think of any at the moment) to indicate a degree of sarcasm/ridicule in a classification system.